# Change the name of the mountpoint used by udisks2

Tags: linux, udev, udisks

The default name is `/run/media/$USER/<UUID>`. Instead of `UUID`, I want it to use the `partlabel` (if it exists), which means I want to change the mountpoint's name to `/run/media/$USER/<partlabel>`.

I was hoping that it is possible by adding a rule (file) in the directory `/etc/udev/rules.d`. Can you tell me what to put in the file?

**Edit** -
This is what is in my rules file. As far as I know, this is the default configuration and there is no effect if it is removed.

```
# UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
# ==1: mount filesystem to a shared directory (/media/VolumeName)
# ==0: mount filesystem to a private directory (/run/media/$USER/VolumeName)
# See udisks(8)
ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem|other|crypto", ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I've understood the `udisks(8)` man page, the default `udisks` rules and my Debian 10 system is comparable to yours, the essential part should be this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{PARTNAME}!="", ENV{UDISKS_NAME}="$env{PARTNAME}"
```

The `PARTLABEL` of e.g. `blkid` output seems to be known as `ENV{PARTNAME}` in udev, or you can use `ENV{ID_PART_ENTRY_NAME}` if you want spaces escaped (i.e. a single space character will become `\x20`).

Comment: I've checked if it was working using `udevadm info`, the variable `UDISKS_NAME` DOES get set to the expected value. However, the mountpoint still stays the same, i.e. `/run/media/$USER/<UUID>` (or `/run/media/$USER/VolumeName` as they call it).

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to choose custom name for the mountpoint. `UDISKS_NAME` mentioned by @telcoM is used only as a hint for the UDisks API users when displaying name of the device -- for example Nautilus/GVFS in GNOME will use it when displaying the mounted devices -- but not for the mountpoint itself. Name for the mountpoint is [hardcoded](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/master/src/udiskslinuxfilesystem.c#L647) and it will be either filesystem label or UUID. Feel free to [report issue against UDisks](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues), using partition label as a third option here sounds like a good idea.